# ggplot does not show legend in geom_histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this code

```
ggplot()
+ geom_histogram(aes(x=V1, y=(..count..)/sum(..count..)), fill="red", alpha=.4, colour="red", data=coding, stat = "bin", binwidth = 30)
+ geom_histogram(aes(x=V1,y=(..count..)/sum(..count..)), fill="blue", alpha=.4, colour="blue", data=lncrna, stat = "bin", binwidth = 30)
+ coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 2000))
+ xlab("Size (nt)")
+ ylab("Percentage (%)")
+ geom_vline(data=cdf, aes(xintercept=rating.mean, colour=Labels), linetype="dashed", size=1)
```

that produces a beautiful histogram without legend:

[image]

In every post I visit with the same problem, they say to put `color` inside `aes`. nevertheless, this does not give any legend.

I tried:

```
ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x=V1, y=(..count..)/sum(..count..),color="red", fill="red"), fill="red", alpha=.4, colour="red", data=coding, stat = "bin", binwidth = 30)
+ geom_histogram(aes(x=V1,y=(..count..)/sum(..count..), color="blue", fill="blue"), fill="blue", alpha=.4, colour="blue", data=lncrna, stat = "bin", binwidth = 30)
+ coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 2000))
+ xlab("Size (nt)")
+ ylab("Percentage (%)")
+ geom_vline(data=cdf, aes(xintercept=rating.mean, colour=Labels), linetype="dashed", size=1)
```

without success.

How can I put a legend in my graph?

Comment: Did you try to specifying fill/color inside the aesthetic mapping? I don't see that in your code. Some [example data](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1412059) would make it easier to show you how to do that.

Comment: what is aesthetic mapping?

Comment: @user2979409: It's the `aes()` function you use.

Comment: Yes, I tried. I updated my post.

Comment: If you specify them inside the aes, you should not specify them outside of it.

Comment: I would combine `coding` and `lncrna` into one object, with an additional column that would tell the data came from (let's say the variable is called `origin`). You map this in `aes()`, e.g. `ggplot(merged.data, aes(..., fill = origin)) + geom_histogram()`. You can control specific colors through scales. See http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/

Answer (score 12):

If you don't want to put the data in one data.frame, you can do this:

```
set.seed(42)
coding <- data.frame(V1=rnorm(1000))
lncrna <- data.frame(V1=rlnorm(1000))


library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + 
  geom_histogram(aes(x=V1, y=(..count..)/sum(..count..), fill="r", colour="r"), alpha=.4, data=coding, stat = "bin") +
  geom_histogram(aes(x=V1,y=(..count..)/sum(..count..), fill="b", colour="b"), alpha=.4, data=lncrna, stat = "bin") +
  scale_colour_manual(name="group", values=c("r" = "red", "b"="blue"), labels=c("b"="blue values", "r"="red values")) +
  scale_fill_manual(name="group", values=c("r" = "red", "b"="blue"), labels=c("b"="blue values", "r"="red values"))
```

[image]

Comment: Can one remove the legend name from the output?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you can't map your color into aes because you've got two separete sets of data. An idea is to bind them, then to apply the "melt" function of package reshape2 so you create a dummy categorical variable that you can pass into aes. the code:

```
require(reshape2)
df=cbind(blue=mtcars$mpg, red=mtcars$mpg*0.8)
df=melt(df, id.vars=1:2)
ggplot()+geom_histogram(aes(y=(..count..)/sum(..count..),x=value, fill=Var2, color=Var2), alpha=.4, data=df, stat = "bin")
```

There you've got your legend

Comment: re: using this, your bars will be either dodged or stacked, but you can tweak the position parameter to superimpose the bars: "position=position_dodge(width=0)"