# manually adding legend to ggplot with different layer types

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Consider the graph below that I created with the code further below.  I would like to add a legend that might say something like "median" and "90% confidence interval."  I've seen this question partially addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24932940/ggplot-does-not-show-legend-in-geom-histogram) (thanks Roland), but when I try to implement it in my own code, the legend looks silly because the middle line doesn't have a fill while the ribbon does.  Is there some way to get the legend to look sensible, where it shows just a line for the middle line and a fill box for the ribbon?

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
middle = data.frame(t=c(0,1,2,3),value=c(0,2,4,6))
ribbon = data.frame(t=c(0,1,2,3),min=c(0,0,0,0),max=c(0,4,8,12))
g = ggplot()
g = g + geom_line  (data=middle,aes(x=t,y=value),color='blue',size=2)
g = g + geom_ribbon(data=ribbon,aes(x=t,ymin=min,ymax=max),alpha=.3,fill='lightblue')
print(g)
```

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
middle = data.frame(t=c(0,1,2,3),value=c(0,2,4,6))
ribbon = data.frame(t=c(0,1,2,3),min=c(0,0,0,0),max=c(0,4,8,12))
g = ggplot()
g = g + geom_ribbon(data=ribbon,aes(x=t,ymin=min,ymax=max,fill="CI" ,color="CI"))
g = g + geom_line  (data=middle,aes(x=t,y=value,                     color="median"))
g = g + scale_colour_manual(values=c("lightblue","blue"))
g = g + scale_fill_manual  (values=c("lightblue"))
print(g)
```

Comment: If you want a legend, map a values to `color` and `fill` inside `aes` and use `scale_color_manual` and `scale_fill_manual` to specify labels and colors.

Comment: Hi Roland, the answer to the hold question only sort of helped.  I tried implementing it (see above), but the legend looks really silly.  Is there some way to get this legend to look sensible?

Answer (score 1):

First, set `guide="none"` for the `scale_fill_manual()` and then use function `guides()` with argument `override.aes=` to change `linetype=` and `fill=` according to line and confidence interval.

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_ribbon(data=ribbon,aes(x=t,ymin=min,ymax=max,fill="CI" ,color="CI")) + 
  geom_line(data=middle,aes(x=t,y=value,color="median"))+ 
  scale_colour_manual("Legend",values=c("lightblue","blue")) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("lightblue"),guide="none")+
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype=c(0,1),fill=c("lightblue","white"))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Didzis.  If anyone knows a more efficient way to do this, that'd be great.  It seems then for graphs like this, ggplot is really not the right plotting environment, just because in other environments, you can get a legend with a single, simple line of code instead of needing multiple lines where you have to specify both the color of the lines and the again, the color of everything in the legend.